# How can a collision event be generated after a certain amount of time?

Tags: timer, coronasdk, collision

I am trying to learn Corona in order to make a 'virtual pet' sort of game. When an Item such as an apple is left on the floor for like 15 seconds I want to attempt to delete and re spawn the item.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want a collision event after a certain time...

You want to check if a object is standing still after 15 seconds!

Just add a enterFrame event to your Runtime.

Then you check for every object if the position changed and set a variable on the object, something like:

```
if myObject.x ~= myObject.lastX and myObject.y ~= myObject.lastY then
    myObject.timeSinceLastMovement = event.time
end

myObject.lastX = myObject.x
myObject.lastY = myObject.y
```

event.time in a enterFrame usually tracks the time since the app started in miliseconds.

Then you check if some object is stopped for 15 seconds.

```
if myObject.timeSinceLastMovement + 15000 < event.time then
    -- code to respawn myObject go here
end
```